# iOS, force quit app first, after tapping the receiving notification banner, app launch failed

Tags: ios, notifications, crash, apple-push-notifications, swipe

I use APNs to send the notifications to my app. But my app does not work well when I did the following steps:

steps

1. swipe the app to force quit (app is not running, not in background mode ..)
2. send the notification from APNs
3. got the notification on my iPhone and I tapped the notification banner
4. app seemed to try to launch(showed the launch image), but launched fail (crash?)

my app can receive notification foreground and background. 
Tap the notification banner in background then it can bring app to foreground then go to the view I wrote, everything works fine.

Except **force quit** the APP

here is my code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                    rightMenuViewController:rightMenuViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction =
    [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];

    // Define an ID string to be passed back to your app when you handle the action
    acceptAction.identifier = @"MARK_AS_READ_IDENTIFIER";

    // Localized string displayed in the action button
    acceptAction.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Mark as Read", nil);

    // If you need to show UI, choose foreground
    acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;

    // Destructive actions display in red
    acceptAction.destructive = NO;

    // Set whether the action requires the user to authenticate
    acceptAction.authenticationRequired = NO;

    // First create the category
    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *inviteCategory =
    [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];

    // Identifier to include in your push payload and local notification
    inviteCategory.identifier = @"actionCategory";

    // Add the actions to the category and set the action context
    [inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    // Set the actions to present in a minimal context
    [inviteCategory setActions:@[acceptAction]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:inviteCategory];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:categories]];

    // for calling didReceiveRemoteNotification when app first launch
    if (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
        NSLog(@"Device token: %@",deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Fail to get device token: %@", error);
}

// tap the backgraund banner button
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)newUserInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MARK_AS_READ_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        // when tapping the background banner's button will mark the notification status to read
        [Functions updateComingNotificationToRead];
    }

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler();
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)newUserInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {
   //NSLog(@"Notification received: %@ %@", newUserInfo,[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] );
    userInfo = newUserInfo;

    NSString *alertMessage = [[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]  objectForKey:@"alert"];
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    UIAlertView *alertView = nil;

    // for background banner use
    switch (state) {
        case UIApplicationStateActive: // when app is alive, show alert to notify user
            alertView =  [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SmartHome",nil) message:NSLocalizedString(alertMessage,nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close",nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Open",nil),NSLocalizedString(@"Mark as Read",nil), nil];
            [alertView show];
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateBackground: // app is in background mode
            // user tap the banner or tap the mark as read button, code will go here
            [Functions addNotificationDataInDatabase:[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"uniqueID"] type:[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"deviceType"] event:[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"event"] time:[newUserInfo objectForKey:@"time"] read:@"0" description:alertMessage];
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateInactive: // tapping the banner
            //NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateInactive");
            // go to notification view
        // because will go to the notification view detail, set status to read
            [self gotoNotificationView:userInfo]; //uniqueID
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    // Handle the received message
    // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);

    // send post notification for updating the badge, will get the notification in foreground
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"APNsNotification" object:self userInfo:nil];

}
```

Does anyone have this problem before? Did I miss something?

Please help me!!

Comment: Did this happen while debugging the app from XCode? The first start after cancelling debugging by forcing the app to close quite often crashes ...

Comment: I force quit my app by swiping the app from the home view, not from Xcode

Comment: Yes, but did you start the app from XCOde when you did that?

Comment: No, I did not start app from Xcode

Answer (score 0):

u can put alert and check launchOptions

```
if (launchOptions) {
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]) {
        [self application:self didReceiveRemoteNotification:[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) {

        }];
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)newUserInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler {

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
NSString *str = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have already add this in my code, it didn't work at all

Comment: please read my code, I had already added what you write. that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Just change      didReceiveRemoteNotification  to  didReceiveRemoteNotification:[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result) { }];

Comment: Hi, Got solution for this?

Comment: u can give green tick on my answer